# LibreOffice Calc #N/A preventing summing after vlookup data is processed

Tags: vlookup, cumulative-sum, libreoffice-calc

How to get rid of the #N/A in G5? I know it's because there's no name in E5 for the vlookup function to produce a result, but I don't want to have to type every single
employee in column E and then manually write in 0 hours.
[image]

Cell G4 says (works)...

```
=F4*VLOOKUP(E4,$Sheet1.$B$4:$Sheet1.$C$6,2,0)
```

and of course G5 (doesn't work as mentioned above) says...

```
=F5*VLOOKUP(E5,$Sheet1.$B$4:$Sheet1.$C$6,2,0)
```

The #N/A in G5 prevents the sum formula in G7 working.
G7 says.... `=SUM(G4:G6)`

In G5 I've tried things like:

```
=if(or(e5="",f5=""),(F6*VLOOKUP(E6,$Sheet1.$B$4:$Sheet1.$C$6,2,0)),"")
```

But LO Calc Gives an Err:504

*p.s. I know 'lookup' can be used here in this extract, but vlookup is being used in the actual master spreadsheet and I want to stick with that method*

Comment: How about `=IFERROR(F4*VLOOKUP(E4;$Sheet1.$B$4:$Sheet1.$C$6;2;0);"")` ? By the way, in your last formula, the addresses are inconsistent - you check for the absence of cell values from row 5, but you calculate the values for row 6 and the results for TRUE and FALSE are reversed. You feel hot?

Comment: Yes, I made some typos (sorry about that)
Your suggestion works fantastically!   THANK YOUUUU. !!!  :D

Comment: Previously on stackoverflow, I could tick a response that answered my question. I don't see such a tick on this occasion. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you didn't miss anything, everything is correct, there is no check mark. The fact is that this was not a full answer, but simply a clarifying comment on your question. It would take a little longer to write a complete and correct answer, and I don't have much of it. You can write a detailed answer to your own question and later accept it as the correct one - this may help those who encounter the same problem.

Comment: To me your comment was a full answer :) as it worked exactly as required.
OK. I'll write your suggestion as an answer in case it's of benefit to others and I really appreciate your 2 inputs here (and others elsewhere). Tq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JohnSUN's comment answered my question. For me, it didn't require
any explanation.

Solve the issue by pasting the IF variant in the cell where #N/A appeared....

```
=IFERROR(F4*VLOOKUP(E4;$Sheet1.$B$4:$Sheet1.$C$6;2;0);"")
```